# How to feed a Keras InputLayer without a model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Let's take the following code as an example:

```
inputs = keras.layers.InputLayer(1).output
output = tf.random.uniform((1, )) * inputs
```

I want to feed `inputs` with value and have it propagate through the layers without using a Keras model.

How can it be done?

Comment: I don't think there is any point on doing this, it is not how the API is meant to be used, you can use tensorflow placeholders instead.

Comment: I'm not sure I get the question. If you are in TF 1.x, then, as suggested, you would probably use a placeholder for that. You could still use `inputs` though, give it a value like `sess.run(output, feed_dict={inputs: some_value})`. In TF 2.x, you would encapsulate that calculation into a function where `inputs` is a parameter, maybe decorate it with [`tf.function`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function) if you want and call it with the value that you need each time.